# Word for secretly practicing another religion or falsely converting to another religion

Tags: vocabulary

There was a word for an act of/a person who secretly practices another religion or falsely converts to a new religion, but I can't recall. Please help!

Comment: Would an example be in 16 century Britain, where people would pretend to be either Catholic or Protestant depending on the reigning monarch to escape persecution?

Comment: What is the word for a person who's persecuted for their religion? That's the term you want. Only someone threatened by society will feel forced to practice their religion  in secret or to convert to a new religion insincerely.

Comment: The only words I know refer to people who secretly practice Judaism (*crypto-Jew* and *marrano*).  Neither word describes the act of conversion, but maybe there's a clue in there.

Comment: Is 'religious migrant' a thing, like 'economic migrant'?

Comment: There are terms for such in particular situations, but they always refer to one persecuted group that does not assimilate to the oppressive religion.

Comment: The modifier I've seen used for that is "crypto," like when Jews, in order to avoid being persecuted for being Jews during the Spanish Inquisition, pretended to be Catholic and outwardly practiced Catholicism while continuing to practice Judaism in private.  These Jews are referred to as "crypto-Jews." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypto-Judaism)

Comment: As others have pointed out, suppression is the prerequisite. *Fugitive religion* and *religious fugitive* have been used this way. But neither are unambiguous without further context.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for '**[Nicodemite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicodemite)**':

> a person who is suspected of public misrepresentation of their actual religious beliefs by exhibiting false appearance and concealing true beliefs.